# how to get special price and regular price in phtml file magento2

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

i have a phtml file where i want to get special and regular price of product im using product model but getting nothing, im using this code:

```
$product_id =$block->getProduct()->getId();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
 
$orgprice = $_product->getPrice();
$specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
```

Comment: Hello @nihal try this code `$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

echo "<pre/>";
print_r($productData);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository to fetch the prices

Comment: not working also

Answer (score 1):

> Use the below code in your class or helper.

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(   
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getSpecialPriceById($id)
{
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    return $product->getSpecialPrice();
}

public function getSpecialPriceBySku($sku)
{   
    $product_id = $block->getProduct()->getId();
    $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    return $product->getSpecialPrice();
}

 public function getPriceById($id)
{
    $product = $this->_productRepository->create();
    return $product->load($id)->getPrice();
}

public function getPriceBySku($sku)
{   
 
    $product = $this->_productRepository->create();
    return $product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku)->getPrice();
}
```

> call this function using block or helper as you want.

```
$id = '1';
$orginalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
$sku = 'some-ski';

//special price
$block->getSpecialPriceById($id);
$block->getSpecialPriceBySku($sku);

//normal price
$block->getPriceById($id);
$block->getPriceBySku($sku);
```

> Please try the below code if you want to use it with object manager
> but it is highly not recommended.

```
$product_id = $block->getProduct()->getId();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->create()->load($product_id);
 
$orginalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
$specialPrice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
```

Comment: i cannot use constructs as i am working in phtml file

Comment: i can use object manager

Comment: it is not recommended practice to write business logic in phtml, also don't use objectmanager as it jacks up the readability. Use blocks to get data/ business logic as suggested in answer.

Comment: yes i know this but for now i have to do this using object manager just to test several logics

Comment: using the above code with object manager gives this error :

Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::create()